# What is the fundamental group of the $3$-manifold bounded by a genus-$2$ torus?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

As in the question, let $X$ be the $3$-manifold bounded by $\partial X$ which is a torus of genus $2$.What is $\pi_1(X)$?

I noted that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R} ^3\backslash X)  \cong \langle a, b | aba^{-1} b^{-1} \rangle$ but I cannot see any commutator relation in $\pi_1(X) $. However I also know that $\pi_1(\partial X) $ has a relation between its four generators. I just cannot see why that does not translate to $\pi_1(X)$.

Comment: Your calculation of $\pi_1(\mathbb R^3\setminus X)$ is not correct. How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Any representative of either of the two generators $[\gamma]$ of $\pi_1(\partial X)$ that goes through one of the "holes" of $\partial X$ is a contractible path in $X$, i.e. the homomorphism $\pi_1(\partial X) \to \pi_1(X)$ induced by the inclusion $\partial X \hookrightarrow X$ is trivial.

Comment: I figured out a mistake in ny drawing. I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your manifold deformation retracts to a figure-eight (or, perhaps more easily, to a figure-$\theta$). Meaning it has fundamental group $\langle a,b\rangle$.